Algorithm for satisfiability of integer inequalities with max
I want to solve satisfiability of integer inequalities with $\max$ efficiently.
Problem:
Find an efficient algorithm for satisfiability in $\mathbb{N}$ of $C$ which is defined by the following BNF:
$$
l := u \mid 0 \mid l + 1 \mid \max \left( l, l \right)
$$
$$
c := l < l \mid l \le l \mid l = l
$$
$$
C := \cdot \mid C , c
$$
These are examples of $C$:
$$
\max \left( 2, u_0 + 1 , u_1 + 3 \right) \le 4 , \max \left( v_0 , v_1 \right) = \max \left( w_0 , w_1 \right)
$$
$$
0 < u , u < v , v < 2
$$
$$
u \le w , v \le w , w + 1 \le \max \left( u , v \right)
$$

Very loosely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness

Thank you for your information!

It seems hard that solving this problem as a betweenness problem because there are no element between $l$ and $l + 1$, but I will consider the possibility that this problem could be NP complete.

I agree. I don't think there is a reduction from the betweenness problem, and I suspect there probably is no direct relationship.  I just thought the problem statement is superficially related so it might also be of interest to others who are interested in your question as well.
